# Url.Content for javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I currently use this approach to obtain the correct relative URI (independent of the deployment situation). Razor code (asp.net mvc 3):

```
@section JavaScript
{  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _getUrl =  "@Url.Content("~/bla/di/bla")";
    </script>
}
```

Separate js file:

```
$.ajax({
    url: _getUrl,
```

Do you reckon there is a better approach?

Comment: Your scripts should be in a separate minimizable/cachable js file.

Comment: I do the same, but I'm not sure if it's a good thing to do. +1 for question :)

Comment: @asawyer - not sure what the point of your comment is ...

Comment: @asawyer "should" is not the correct word. In .NET 4.5 you can do this, however, you couldn't solve this issue with that!

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9 The only issue I see here is that csetzkorn should be using `@Url.Action` or possibly `@Url.RouteUrl` not `@Url.Content`

Comment: @asawyer Agreed - see my answer.

Comment: I also use this approach, sometimes I also think must be some better, but I have not  found any better alternative. @asawyer is right, you should use  '@Url.Action' when you want to get an URL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally I prefer using HTML5 data-* attributes or including the URL as part of some DOM element that I unobtrusively AJAXify.

The thing is that you never write `$.ajax` calls flying around like that. You write them to correspond to some DOM events. Like for example clicking of an anchor. In this case it's trivial, you just use an HTML helper to generate this anchor:

```
@Html.ActionLink("click me", "someAction", "somecontroller", new { id = "123" }, new { @class = "link" })
```

and then:

```
$('.link').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(result) {
            ...
        }

    });
    return false;
});
```

or maybe you are AJAXifying a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SomeAction", "SomeController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
{
    ...
}
```

and then:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
            ...
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Another example would be to use HTML5 data-* attributes when an appropriate url is not available on the corresponding DOM element. Suppose that you want to invoke a controller action with AJAX when the selection of a dropdown changes. Think for example cascading ddls.

Here's how your dropdown might look like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.Values, new { id = "myDdl", data_url = Url.Action("SomeAction") })
```

and then:

```
$('#myDdl').change(function() {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    var selectedValue =  $(this).val();
    $.getJSON(url, { id: selectedValue }, function(result) {
        ...
    });
});
```

So as you can see you don't really need this `_getUrl` global javascript variable that you declared in your view.

Comment: +1 I was about to type up an example of this but you have it succinctness written. Plus I should point out I'm pretty sure I learned the technique from you.

Comment: @darin-dimitrov that's a pretty good answer. Although may add unneccessary html to the page in certain circumstances (eg if a "click" didn't make sense and you needed to use a hidden field or other DOM element just to store the value).

Comment: Why would it be unnecessary? This allows for your application still function even with javascript disabled. This is called progressive enhancement.

Comment: @darindimitrov Yes, but that wasn't the question. If he'd have asked "how do I get the url from a hyperlink and make an ajax call with it" then your answer would be perfect.

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9, that's probably because the OP didn't know about this technique. Now that he knows it he realizes that he doesn't need the global javascript variable in his view at all.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Hope he edits the question then otherwise it's confusing to accept this answer, albeit a very good one.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

**Razor C# script** before Javascript

```
@{
    var myUrlString = Url.Action("ActionName", new { controller="ControllerName" });
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$.ajax('@myUrlString',{
    // options
});
```

You could also use `Url.RouteUrl` or `Url.HttpRouteUrl`.

**EDIT - showing example with separated JS file**

*Razor*

```
@{
    var myServerGeneratedValue = Url.Action("ActionName", new{controller="ControllerName"});
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myHelperObject = new MyHelperObject();
    myHelperObject.Init('@myServerGeneratedValue');
</script>
```

*JS file*

```
var MyHelperObject = function(){

    this.Init = function(serverGeneratedValue){
        // do something with serverGeneratedValue
    };

};
```

Comment: The action name can be a string, the anon type is unnecessary.

Comment: I like this as it makes sure that the outgoing URIs are kept in synch if the routing changes. However, this requires the javascript code to sit in the view!

Comment: @asawyer The action name **is** a string and the "anon type" is necessary if you are routing to a different controller / area from the current. Also how would you add IDs or any other routing data without it??

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9 Er sorry I meant Controller name.

Comment: @csetzkorn Correct, yes, but you could also have the **majority** of your script in a separate file and just pass the server-generated data to a constructor or "init" method in a JavaScript object

Comment: This will only work with inline javascript. In a separate javascript files (which of course is the correct place to put your js logic) you cannot use server side helpers.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - see example above. Best of both worlds?

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9, but why duplicating this url when it could already be present in your DOM? What's the point of this global javascript variable? The whole point of my answer is that you don't need it because you already have tyhis information present in your DOM in one form or another.

Comment: It's not "duplicating!". If there's no reason to have it in your DOM other than to pass it's value to a JavaScript function / object, then don't have it in your DOM! It will only appear once, when being passed to the "Init" method of "MyHelperObject". I agree, if it's already **in** the DOM then you don't need to do this. But that wasn't the question.

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9, I see, it's just that I don't like writing javascript code in my markup. I prefer to have them separated.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Agreed - it's not ideal to have them "linked". But sometimes you need to pass dynamic server-side values to JavaScript - there is sometimes no other way.

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9, agreed with you. It's just that those cases are very rare and there are usually other ways. Maybe we need a specific example to discuss upon.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov (last comment as we're virtually having a chat!) but yes they are rare in "Progressive Enhancement" world - but in a complex web application where PE or GD isn't an option (like a CMS) you often need to pass server-generated data to JavaScript like this (speaking from experience!!).